# Using objectFilter to limit output of Softlayer's REST APIs?

Tags: rest, curl, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to curl the list of images that I have available on Softlayer. My current curl command is:

```
curl 'https://USERNAME:API_KEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getBlockDeviceTemplateGroups.xml?objectMask=filteredMask\[id,name\]&objectFilter=\{"id":\{"operation":111111\}\}'`
```

But it doesn't work. The `objectMask` works, but the `objectFilter` seems to be letting everything through, and I still see every image (not only the one whose id is `111111`). Am I structuring my URL wrong at the end...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the structure that you need to send:

```
curl "https://USERNAME:API_KEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getBlockDeviceTemplateGroups.xml?objectFilter={"blockDeviceTemplateGroups":{"id":{"operation":"111111"}}}&objectMask=id;name"
```

Unfortunately, it's necessary to escape the special characters using cURL, so you can send this ( object filter is encoding):

```
curl "https://USERNAME:API_KEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getBlockDeviceTemplateGroups.xml?objectFilter=%7B%22blockDeviceTemplateGroups%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%7B%22operation%22%3A%22111111%22%7D%7D%7D&objectMask=id;name"
```

Replace: **USERNAME**, **API_KEY** and **111111**

e.g:

> %22%3A%22**111111**%22%7D%7D%7D

**References**:

- [SoftLayer_Account/getBlockDeviceTemplateGroups](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getBlockDeviceTemplateGroups)
- [Object Filters](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters)

Comment: Found out that the escaping was unnecessary as long as I passed a -g flag to curl, and enclosed the url in single quotes. But this worked great for me! Thanks so much!